# /var/run/utmp is getting large and slowing my server down

Tags: log-files

I removed it and touched an empty verison a few weeks ago and noticed a big upswing in performance for my server. The file was 400+ MB. I've been keeping an eye on it since and I'm noticing it is growing fairly quickly. I tailed the file and I'm seeing a lot of "TTYXXLOGIN" entries. Should I be concerned? Is there a way to minimize it's logging? Should I logrotate it and forget about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of I all think you need to understand that /var/run/utmp is not a log file (otherwise it would have been in /var/log). It is a file used by the system to store information about the [current use of the machine](http://linux.die.net/man/5/utmp). Its content is normally managed by the applications using the file.

Perhaps it would be a good idea if you looked into what is actually causing all those entries in the file to be made in the first place? Do you perhaps have programs performing logins without proper exits when done?